# Maximal ideals of $D$.

Tags: ring-theory

> Let $D=\{\,f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\mid f\mbox{ is twice differentiable}\,\}$ be a ring and let $J=\{f\in D\,|\, f'(0)=f(0)=0\}$ be an ideal in D. Find all maximal ideals of $D$ that contain $J$.

I proved that at least the set $M_1=\{f\in D\mid f(0)=0\}$ is maximal ideal that contains $J$. But I'm not sure as prove that exist other ideals.

Comment: $M_2$ is not even an ideal. We have $1 \in M_2$ but $M_2 \neq D$.

Comment: Yes ok, I have an error.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we have $M_1 \supset J \supset M_1^2$. Hence $M_1$ is the only maximal ideal containing $J$.

Comment: All right, thank MooS, Based in your observation, I suppose that exist other maximal ideal $K$ such that $K\supset J$, as $M_1^2\subset J$, this implies that $M_1^2\subset K$. Since $M_1$ and $K$ are maximal ideals then $K=M_1$. So $M_1$ is the only maximal ideal containing $J$.

Comment: I never imagined this special subring of the ring of continuous functions would admit such a trick. Very cool!

Comment: @AlexCg. Your last step between $M_1^2\subseteq K$ to $K=M_1$ is not totally clear, but it is correct: by primeness of $K$, you have $M_1\subseteq K$, and by maximality of $M_1$ they are equal.